# Why did Kamala wear her bangle at the end of "The Marvels" (2023)?

Tags: marvel, marvel-cinematic-universe, character-motivation, ms-marvel, the-marvels

If Kamala's powers were unlocked by her grandmother's bangle, but not necessary for her to sustain her powers, why did she wear the bangle at the end of *The Marvels* if she didn't need it to have powers? Doesn't that just make it easy for the villain to win?

Answer (score 6):

After Kamala has helped get her family to the escape pod, and just as she is about to join the other two Marvels in the final fight, Kamala explains to Fury:

> Dar-Benn’s opened another jump point…
>
> and we’re gonna need both bangles to close it.